# Unable to resolve dependency tree - React Native Expo

Tags: react-native, npm, dependencies, expo, node-modules

I have been starting my story with React Native (Expo). Someday I needed to install `datetimepicker`. Unfortunately, I have done something wrong. I tried to face the problem by myself. I removed the `node_modeles` directory and `package.lock.json`. When I trying to `npm install` I get the error below:

error message

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: undefined@undefined
npm ERR! Found: react@16.13.1
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"16.13.1" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@">=16.8.3" from @react-native-community/datetimepicker@3.4.6
npm ERR!   node_modules/@react-native-community/datetimepicker
npm ERR!     @react-native-community/datetimepicker@"^3.0.4" from the root project
npm ERR!   1 more (react-native)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"17.0.1" from react-native-windows@0.64.3
npm ERR! node_modules/react-native-windows
npm ERR!   peer react-native-windows@">=0.62" from @react-native-community/datetimepicker@3.4.6
npm ERR!   node_modules/@react-native-community/datetimepicker
npm ERR!     @react-native-community/datetimepicker@"^3.0.4" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

I know that is something with the wrong versions of dependencies but I have no idea how to fixed it :(
That is my package.json.

UPDATED `package.json`

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.13.0",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "1.9.11",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.11.10",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.12.5",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.4",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.14.4",
    "@types/expo__vector-icons": "^9.0.1",
    "expo": "~41.0.0",
    "expo-app-loading": "^1.0.3",
    "expo-notifications": "~0.11.5",
    "expo-sms": "~9.1.2",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.0.4",
    "i18n-js": "^3.8.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-41.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.10.2",
    "react-native-pager-view": "5.0.12",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~1.13.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.2.0",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.0.0",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^3.0.1",
    "react-native-web": "^0.13.18",
    "react-native-webview": "11.2.3",
    "react-navigation-header-buttons": "^7.0.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.3",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "~7.9.0",
    "@types/i18n-js": "^3.8.0",
    "@types/react": "~16.9.35",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.3",
    "@types/react-native": "~0.63.2",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.16",
    "typescript": "~4.0.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

How can I make it working again?

---

### UPDATE #1

I have created a new project and I have installed all dependencies by expo install without `react-native-modal-datetime-picker`. I have copied and dependencies to my original project. When I used npm install my project installed correctly with the message:

```
22:39 $ npm install
npm WARN deprecated deep-assign@3.0.0: Check out `lodash.merge` or `merge-options` instead.
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/topo@3.1.6: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/bourne@1.3.2: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/address@2.1.4: Moved to 'npm install @sideway/address'
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/hoek@8.5.1: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated uglify-es@3.3.9: support for ECMAScript is superseded by `uglify-js` as of v3.13.0
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/joi@15.1.1: Switch to 'npm install joi'
npm WARN deprecated core-js@1.2.7: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.12: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.12: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.12: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.12: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.12: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.

added 1087 packages, and audited 1088 packages in 30s

60 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

12 low severity vulnerabilities

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force

Run `npm audit` for details.
```

Right now I'm trying to install `react-native-modal-datetime-picker` (https://github.com/mmazzarolo/react-native-modal-datetime-picker) and I'm getting error:

```
22:44 $ expo install react-native-modal-datetime-picker @react-native-community/datetimepicker
Installing 1 SDK 41.0.0 compatible native module and 1 other package using npm.
> npm install
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: undefined@undefined
npm ERR! Found: react@16.13.1
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"16.13.1" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@">=16.8.3" from @react-native-community/datetimepicker@3.2.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@react-native-community/datetimepicker
npm ERR!     @react-native-community/datetimepicker@"3.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   1 more (react-native)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"17.0.1" from react-native-windows@0.64.3
npm ERR! node_modules/react-native-windows
npm ERR!   peer react-native-windows@">=0.62" from @react-native-community/datetimepicker@3.2.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@react-native-community/datetimepicker
npm ERR!     @react-native-community/datetimepicker@"3.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /home/adas/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/adas/.npm/_logs/2021-04-17T20_53_05_643Z-debug.log

npm exited with non-zero code: 1
Error: npm exited with non-zero code: 1
    at ChildProcess.completionListener (/home/adas/.nvm/versions/node/v14.16.0/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/spawn-async/src/spawnAsync.ts:65:13)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:422:26)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:467:12)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1048:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5)
    ...
    at Object.spawnAsync [as default] (/home/adas/.nvm/versions/node/v14.16.0/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/spawn-async/src/spawnAsync.ts:26:19)
    at NpmPackageManager._runAsync (/home/adas/.nvm/versions/node/v14.16.0/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/package-manager/src/NodePackageManagers.ts:166:31)
    at NpmPackageManager.addAsync (/home/adas/.nvm/versions/node/v14.16.0/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/package-manager/src/NodePackageManagers.ts:105:18)
    at installAsync (/home/adas/.nvm/versions/node/v14.16.0/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/src/commands/install.ts:130:3)
    at Command.<anonymous> (/home/adas/.nvm/versions/node/v14.16.0/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/src/exp.ts:349:7)
```

Comment: i am experienceing the exact same issue. i was just wondering if i posted this question and forgot about it.

Answer (score 9):

Try Updating packages to the latest version.

```
npm update
```

give a try to install with `--force` flag as well if the update has not worked. eg:

```
npm install --force
```

Comment: You can  just use --force flag to accept the warnings.. Hopefully that will work!

Comment: `--force` float with `npm install` worked for me

Answer (score 0):

try running this:

```
npm install --legacy-peer-deps --global expo-cli
```